# Unable to Saveas using ComObject Outlook.Application

Tags: powershell, outlook

why do I get this error ``` Operation aborted (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80004004 (E_ABORT))
At line:12 char:5

- ```
  $msg.SaveAs($docFullName, 4)
  ```
- ```
  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  ```

  - CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: (:) [], COMException
  - FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException ```

```
$outlook = New-Object -ComObject Outlook.Application
$word = New-Object -ComObject Word.Application

Get-ChildItem -Path $folderPath -Filter *.msg? | ForEach-Object {

    $msgFullName = $_.FullName
    $docFullName = $msgFullName -replace '\.msg$', '.doc'
    $pdfFullName = $msgFullName -replace '\.msg$', '.pdf'

    $msg = $outlook.CreateItemFromTemplate($msgFullName)
    $msg.SaveAs($docFullName, 4)

    $doc = $word.Documents.Open($docFullName)
    $doc.SaveAs([ref] $pdfFullName, [ref] 17)

    $doc.Close()
 }
```